# Why does my Spring controller, instead of displaying a view, download an empty file when the path is accessed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

So I have a controller in Spring Boot application that looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView register() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("register");
        mav.addObject("user", new User());

        return mav;
    }
}
```

What I want to happen, is for my jsp page, located at webapp/jsp/register.jsp, to be displayed with an attribute attached to the model that I want to use for a form on the page. What ends up happening is that when I try to access this file from my index.html page, located at webapp/index.html, is that my browser just downloads a file and no view is displayed.

[What happens when I try to access /register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdPLz.png)

I have `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /jsp/` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp` in my application.properties file.

Comment: What if you remove @ResponseBody annotation?

Comment: how do you access the file from index.html? Do you use any custom View resolver?

Comment: @elyor Same thing happens. What I don't understand is that this setup worked on a previous application I made, and for some reason doesn't anymore. Could it be a problem with dependencies?

Comment: i think you can not use ResponseBody and ModelAndView

Comment: @DonCziken `<a href="/register">Register</a>`

Comment: what you can try to do is

removing @ResponseBody as others suggested and add produces setting to RequestMapping annotnation like:

RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/html;charset=UTF-8")

more at:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not added "tomcat-jasper"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>{version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot contains embedded Tomcat server, but you should add tomcat-jasper dependency to parse JSP.